# Passing variable to href

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

How can I get const targetCV to the href?

This function, on click, is supposed to get targetCV and fetch the file if lang = pt or lang = en

```
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

const CTA = () => {
    const { t, i18next } = useTranslation();

    const onDownloadCV = () => {
        const lang = i18next.language;
        if(lang === "pt" || lang === "en"){
            const targetCV = require(`../assets/cv_${lang}.pdf`);
        }
    };

    return(
        <div className="cta">
            <a href={} onClick={onDownloadCV} download className="btn">{t("downloadCV")}</a>
            <a href="#contact" className="btn btn-primary">{t("contactButton")}</a>
        </div>
    );
};

export default CTA;
```

Comment: Maybe `<a href={\`/assets/cv_${i18next.language}.pdf\`} download/>` but the PDF file doesn't come from your source code but from the server, not sure if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set first the link with required language. No need to import as module since you have those files in a static folder.

```
const CTA = () {
  const { t, i18next } = useTranslation()
  const targetCV = `../assets/cv_${i18next.language}.pdf`
  return(
    <div className="cta">
      <a href={targetCV} download className="btn">
        {t("downloadCV")}
      </a>
      <a href="#contact" className="btn btn-primary">{t("contactButton")}</a>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: but I only have files for pt and en though, shouldn't I use an if to avoid errors if the browser searches for another language other than those?